# Extraer dos fechas diferentes en mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Quiero extraer el mes 7 o el 10, pero no se cual sería la forma correcta, tengo los siguientes códigos, y no se cual estaría bien:

```
and extract(month from o.fecha) = 7 or 10

and (extract(month from o.fecha) = 7 or extract(month from o.fecha) = 10)
```

Comment: Hola Alexander, ¿podrías ponernos el bloque de código en el que estás trabajando? Así podríamos ayudarte de mejor forma.

Comment: si lo probas.. vas a ver que uno da un claro error.. y el otro (Si la funcion extract es correcta) funciona... lo que puede ser es que le falten parentesis...

Comment: `and month(o.fecha) in (7,10)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entiendo que estás usando la función dentro de un IF.

Te funcionará de la manera esperada usando la segunda opción:

```
(extract(month from o.fecha) = 7 or extract(month from o.fecha) = 10)
```